# Keep UI Text Input after adding or removing Inputs

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, textinput

I'm building a small UI where a user will enter into a splitLayout row of text that builds a statement (not needed for this question) to solve a puzzle.

[image: First Input]

However, if the user decides he/she needs an **additional** row **or less** rows to solve the puzzle I'd like adding or removing a new row of inputs to NOT delete the remaining input rows.

[image: Second Input Attempt] * the gray is a placeholder.

How can I best achieve my desired result of:

[image]

Please find my trimmed code below. Thanks for your input.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Identify A, B and C"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 5,
                 helpText("Present a statement and receive a response: 1 is a Knight who always tells the truth, 2 is a Knave who always lies, and 3 is a Normal who can do either."),
                 # Number of Questions
                 numericInput(inputId = "Questions", label = "Number of Questions", 
                              value = 1, min = 1, max = 10, step = 1),
                 splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%","70%"), 
                             style = "border: 1px solid silver;",
                             cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 3px"),
                             uiOutput("textQuestions"), uiOutput("textQuestions2"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # Right hand side output
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  ####### I don't want these to delete initially everytime??
  output$textQuestions <- renderUI({
    Questions <- as.integer(input$Questions)
    lapply(1:Questions, function(i) {
      textInput(inputId = paste0("Who", i), label = paste0(i, ". Ask:"), placeholder = "A")
    })
  })
  ########
  output$textQuestions2 <- renderUI({
    Questions <- as.integer(input$Questions)
    lapply(1:Questions, function(i) {
      textInput(inputId = paste0("Q", i) , label = paste0("Logic:"), 
                value = "", placeholder = "A == 1 & (B != 2 | C == 3)")
    })
  })
  ######
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This seems like a good use-case for the `insertUI` `removeUI` workflow: https://gallery.shinyapps.io/111-insert-ui/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like someone already gave you an answer using `uiOutput`+`renderUI`, so I'm going to go the other route: using `insertUI` and `removeUI`.

Instead of having a numeric input for "number of questions", I replaced it with a button for "add question" and one for "remove question". I have a variable keeping track of how many questions there are. Every time "add question" is pressed, we add one row. When "remove question" is pressed, we remove the last row.

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Identify A, B and C"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 5,
      helpText("Present a statement and receive a response: 1 is a Knight who always tells the truth, 2 is a Knave who always lies, and 3 is a Normal who can do either."),
      # Buttons to add/remove a question
      actionButton("add", "Add question"),
      actionButton("remove", "Remove question"),
      div(id = "questions",
          style = "border: 1px solid silver;")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # Right hand side output
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Keep track of the number of questions
  values <- reactiveValues(num_questions = 0)

  # Add a question
  observeEvent(input$add, ignoreNULL = FALSE, {
    values$num_questions <- values$num_questions + 1
    num <- values$num_questions
    insertUI(
      selector = "#questions", where = "beforeEnd",
      splitLayout(
        cellWidths = c("25%","70%"), 
        cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 3px"),
        id = paste0("question", num),
        textInput(inputId = paste0("Who", num),
                  label = paste0(num, ". Ask:"),
                  placeholder = "A"),
        textInput(inputId = paste0("Q", num) ,
                  label = paste0("Logic:"),
                  placeholder = "A == 1 & (B != 2 | C == 3)")
      )
    )
  })

  # Remove a question
  observeEvent(input$remove, {
    num <- values$num_questions
    # Don't let the user remove the very first question
    if (num == 1) {
      return()
    }
    removeUI(selector = paste0("#question", num))
    values$num_questions <- values$num_questions - 1
  })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**EDIT**

OP requested a way to retrieve the user's input based on a question number. To do that:

1. Add the following to the UI

   ```
   numericInput("question_num", "Show question number", 1),
   textOutput("question")
   ```
2. Add the following to the server

   ```
   get_question <- function(q) {
     paste(
       input[[paste0("Who", q)]],
       ":",
       input[[paste0("Q", q)]]
     )
   }

   output$question <- renderText({
     get_question(input$question_num)
   })
   ```

Comment: Dean, this is exactly what I need thank you, but as I'm new to InsertUI and removeUI would you mind also providing the way of calling the user's input values as well? say in a simple function(Who, Q)?

Comment: @EvanFriedland added that to my answer, after the **EDIT** block

Comment: In "19 hours" you shall have the bounty :) Thank you for your help. Is there a simple way to call all of the Who# inputs and Q# inputs as 2 separate lists?

Comment: Actually I believe that is a separate question entirely, I will do some more searching on my own. Thank  you Dean.

Answer (score 2):

You could store it in a reactive value:

```
  global <- reactiveValues(ask = c(), logic = c())

  observe({
    Questions <- as.integer(input$Questions)
    lapply(1:Questions, function(i) {
      inputVal <- input[[paste0("Who", i)]]
      if(!is.null(inputVal)){
        global$logic[i] <- inputVal
      }
      inputValQ <- input[[paste0("Q", i)]]
      if(!is.null(inputValQ)){
        global$ask[i] <- inputValQ
      }
    })
  })
```

That would yield the following code for you example:
As a side effect the values would also be stored if a input was removed and then retaken.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Identify A, B and C"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 5,
                 helpText("Present a statement and receive a response: 1 is a Knight who always tells the truth, 2 is a Knave who always lies, and 3 is a Normal who can do either."),
                 # Number of Questions
                 numericInput(inputId = "Questions", label = "Number of Questions", 
                              value = 1, min = 1, max = 10, step = 1),
                 splitLayout(cellWidths = c("25%","70%"), 
                             style = "border: 1px solid silver;",
                             cellArgs = list(style = "padding: 3px"),
                             uiOutput("textQuestions"), uiOutput("textQuestions2"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # Right hand side output
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic 
server <- function(input, output) {
  global <- reactiveValues(ask = c(), logic = c())

  observe({
    Questions <- as.integer(input$Questions)
    lapply(1:Questions, function(i) {
      inputVal <- input[[paste0("Who", i)]]
      if(!is.null(inputVal)){
        global$ask[i] <- inputVal
      }
      inputValQ <- input[[paste0("Q", i)]]
      if(!is.null(inputValQ)){
        global$logic[i] <- inputValQ
      }
    })
  })
  ####### I don't want these to delete initially everytime??
  output$textQuestions <- renderUI({
    Questions <- as.integer(input$Questions)
    lapply(1:Questions, function(i) {
      textInput(inputId = paste0("Who", i), label = paste0(i, ". Ask:"), placeholder = "A", value = global$ask[i])
    })
  })
  ########
  output$textQuestions2 <- renderUI({
    Questions <- as.integer(input$Questions)
    lapply(1:Questions, function(i) {
      textInput(inputId = paste0("Q", i) , label = paste0("Logic:"), value = global$logic[i],
                placeholder = "A == 1 & (B != 2 | C == 3)")
    })
  })
  ######
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: BigD, thank you for your response. I am inspecting your code and am unable to connect the global$ask and $logic with the uiOutput I desire. I also had to swap the names within the lapply as global$logic should be coming from "Q" and global$ask should be coming from "Who". Thank you for pointing me to reactiveValues as it does appear to be in the direction of the answer I need.

Comment: Oh, yes I mixed up sthg in the notation, I corrected that. However, besides variable names is there sthg missing in the functionality? When I run the code the values dont get reset, but stay as desired - what are you seeing when you run the code?

Comment: Apologies** it does indeed remain, but after removing the rows, is it possible to reset the textInputs that are no longer viewed on the ui?

Comment: Good question: That was the "side effect" I was talking about. I will look into that later, that is possible for sure. It would be interesting as well to consider rewriting the shiny function renderUI, so that you dont need to have big code block for a small functionality ;)

Comment: I like the way you think- I will look back later and edit think about a renderDynamicUI function after I get off of a flight. Cheers

Comment: I'm such a shiny noob. Any headway/tips you may be able to give me for this step?